# Calculate sum of series $\sum \frac{n^2}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to calculate sum of series $\sum \frac{n^2}{n!}$. I know that $\sum \frac{1}{n!}=e$ but I dont know how can I use that fact here..

Comment: Ok I know. Its 2e

Answer (score 13):

HINT
$$\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n^2}{n\cdot (n-1)!}=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!}=\frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Gotta be careful in the case $n=1$, of course...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think it's a fairly common convention to let $\frac1{n!}$ equal $0$ when $n$ is a negative integer (even though, _strictly speaking_, it's not true).

Comment: Really? I've never seen that convention, *ever*, and I've done a lot of math. @columbus8myhw

Comment: Either one, but the second one was really broad. @columbus8myhw

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You know how $\binom nk$ is, by convention, $0$ when $n<k$? Also, $\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!}\cdot\frac1{(n-k)!}$. Taking the case where $n<k$, this kind of implies that $\frac1{(n-k)!}=0$ (note that $n-k$ is negative here).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In addition, it gives the right answer in this context (i.e. kingW3's post). $\frac{1^2}{1!}=0+\frac1{(1-1)!}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Also, I recently-ish ran into a sum involving logarithms, where one of the terms is undefined (though the limit as $n$ went to its value was defined). If I interpreted that term to mean it's _limit_, I got the right answer. EDIT: [This thing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953843/digamma-equation-identification). To avoid confusion I wrote $\rho\neq1$ under the sum sign.

Comment: If the limit isn't zero, then the sum is undefined, always. You'd still have to given an *argument* for why that works. You can't simply assert it. That's bad math. You can easily get right answers for wrong reasons, develop bad habits, and start to get wrong answers without knowing it later. @columbus8myhw

Comment: @ThomasAndrews http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28-1%29%21

Answer (score 8):

Apply the operator $DxD$, where $D=\frac{d}{dx} $, to

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n} {n!} = e^x $$

and then substitute $x=1$. See [similar techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385067/closed-form-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-n4-h-n2n).

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

Let $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$.
Express
$
g(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2x^{n}}{n!}
$
in terms of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$.

Interpret the result using $f(x)=e^x$.