# Compute $\frac{1}{e}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{k}}{n!}$ for $k=0, 1, 2 ... $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Using some matlab (I know it's cheating) I found that:
$$k=0 => Result=1$$
$$k=1 => Result=1$$
$$k=2 => Result=2$$
$$k=3 => Result=5$$
$$k=4 => Result=15$$
$$k=5 => Result=52$$
$$k=6 => Result=203$$

This sequence is puzzling...

Comment: Am I right that these are rounded results?

Comment: [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)

Comment: But you don't seem to be asking a question, Chris.

Comment: The results for k=0,1,2,3 are accurate. I computed the series by hand. The others are rounded, but they converged very quickly with accuracy of 10 zeros after the point.
My question is what is the sequence $a_k=\frac{1}{e}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{k}}{n!}$.
achille hui recognized the numbers as Bell Numbers, but how do you prove it?

Comment: Thanks achille hui. I didn't know about Bell Numbers. I'm going to read about them right now!

Comment: *This sequence is puzzling...* - Puzzling or not, it's still a *sequence*... and the [site for integer sequences](http://oeis.org/) is...

Comment: It may interest you that this is the third time in two weeks this sum has appeared here i.e. at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242818/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\Large\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb e^{nx}}{n!}=\mathbb e^{\mathbb e^x}-1$$

$$~$$

$$\Large\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{n!}=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(\mathbb e^{\mathbb e^x}-1)\huge]_{x=0}$$

Comment: I hope this is what OP wants, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I don't Know What mean OP?

Comment: Original Poster, the person who posted the question.

Comment: hmm...where's $j$?

Comment: What is $\frac{e^{nx}}{!}$?

Comment: Thank you. It was a Typographical error.