# How can I evaluate the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ n^2}{n!} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, factorial

Can someone help me to evaluate

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n!}?$$

It can be written as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!},$$ but I am unable to analyze this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check for convergence?

Comment: it can be helpful though

Comment: Hint: From where you got to, rewrite the numerator $n$ as $(n-1)+1$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266331/compute-frac1e-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracnkn-for-k-0-1-2/1266344#1266344)

Comment: See [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula) for [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: See also [What's the value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44113) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/44113).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got a very good start. Now rewrite the numerator $n$ as $(n-1)+1$. Our sum is equal to
$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!}.$$
By the method you already used, the first sum is $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{(n-2)!}$. This sum is $e$. More simply, the second sum is $e$.

Comment: than answer comes 2e

Comment: Yes, it is $2e$.

Answer (score 2):

Factorials in denominator are always appealing. So start writing $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ n^2}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ n(n-1)+n}{n!}x^n=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ n(n-1)}{n!}x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ n}{n!}x^{n-1}$$  Recognize that the first sum is the second derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ x^n}{n!}=e^x$ and that the second sum is the first derivative of the same quantity. So $$S=x^2 e^x+x e^x=x(x+1)e^x$$ Now, replace $x$ by $1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** We can (after reindexing and checking convergence) write the sum as the value of the series
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1}{n!} x^n$$
at $x = 1$.

> **Additional hint** The appearance of $(n + 1) x^n$ in the summand suggests that we rewrite this as $$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} x^{n + 1} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} x^n\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}xe^x|_{x=1}=2e
$$