# Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{n!}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I have to find the sum of the following series:
 $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{n!}$$

I know how to prove the convergence of this series, but how do i find the sum. I can't use the properties of derivation or integration of the series, i have to do it using the definition that a series converges iff it's sequence of partial sum converges.

Comment: Writing $n^3$ as $n (n - 1) (n - 2) + 3 n (n - 1) + n$ might be a good place to start (and then using that $e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: Here is a question about a generalization: [Compute $\frac{1}{e}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{k}}{n!}$ for $k=0, 1, 2 ... $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266331)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on @Winther's comment, you may write

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{n!}&=\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n (n - 1) (n - 2) + 3 n (n - 1) + n}{n!}\\\\
> &=\sum_3^{\infty} \frac{n (n - 1) (n - 2)}{n!}+3\sum_2^{\infty} \frac{n(n - 1) }{n!}+\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}\\\\
> &=\sum_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-3)!}+3\sum_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\\\\
> &=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}+3\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}+\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\\\\
> &=5e
> \end{align}
> $$

since
$$
\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x, \quad x \in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

In general, if

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3 a_n z^n = \frac{d}{dz} \left [z   \frac{d}{dz} \left [z \frac{d}{dz} f(z) \right ]\right ]$$

In your case $a_n = 1/n!$ implies that $f(z) = e^z$.  Take the derivatives, set $z=1$.  The result is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{n!} = 5 e$$

Comment: How can one find $f$ forn $a_n$? Just curious, if it is long, I'll ask a question about it.

Comment: @wythagoras: Well, it helps to be familiar with some basic Taylor series, such as that for $e^z$.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but as I said I can't use derivatives or integrals, because in this curse I'm learning only the basics (Analysis 1), in Analysis 2 I learn derivatives and integrals, so that is the main problem...

Comment: Then you may want to read the comment from @Winther.  Again, that assumes you know how to recognize a famous series for $e$.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have given you different ways to solve the problem at hand. I will below just add some notes on how one can evaluate general sums on the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{n!}$ where $k$ is any integer using just algebraic manipulations (since you said you cannot use derivatives). I'm however assuming we already know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} = e$.

We start by noting that we can always write $n^k$ on the form

$$n^k = C_1n + C_2n(n-1) + \ldots + C_kn(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) \equiv \sum_{j=1}^{k} C_j{n\choose j}j!$$

where $C_i$ are some real numbers (see below for a simple algorithm to compute these numbers). For example

$$n^2 = n(n-1) + n$$
and
$$n^4 = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) +  6 n (n - 1) (n - 2) + 7 n (n - 1) + n$$

The reason this form is useful is that we can very easily evaluate the sums

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-i)}{n!} = \sum_{n=i+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-i-1)!} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!} = e$$

where we have simply shifted the summation index to $m = n-i-1$ in the last step. The sum above does not depend on $i$ at all so the sum we are after becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ C_1n + C_2n(n-1) + \ldots + C_kn(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n!} \\= C_1 e + C_2 e + \ldots + C_k e =  \left(\sum_{j=1}^k C_j\right) e$$

so the problem reduces to finding the $C_i$'s.

---

Here is a simple method to compute the $C_i$'s. Lets take $k=3$ as an example and start by writing 
$$n^3 = \color{blue}{1}n^3$$
Now we subtract $\color{blue}{1}n(n-1)(n-2)$ to get
$$n^3 - \color{blue}{1} n(n-1)(n-2) = \color{red}{3} n^2 - 2n$$
so $C_2 = \color{red}{3}$. Now subtract $\color{red}{3}n(n-1)$ to get
$$n^3 - n(n-1)(n-2) - \color{red}{3}n(n-1) = \color{pink}{1} n$$
so $C_1 = \color{pink}{1}$. We have now shown that
$$n^3 = \color{blue}{1}n(n-1)(n-2) + \color{red}{3}n(n-1) + \color{pink}{1} n$$
so using the formula above we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^3}{n!} = (\color{blue}{1}+\color{red}{3}+\color{pink}{1})e = 5e$$

---

If you want to read more about this, the numbers $C_j$ are the so-called [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $C_j \equiv S(k,j)$, and the sum $\sum_{j=1}^k C_j = \sum_{j=1}^k S(k,j) \equiv B_k$ are the so-called $k$'th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) (and is always an integer). Using this the final result can be compactly written

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{n!} = eB_k$$

which is known as [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula). Knowing this there exist an even simpler method to compute the Bell numbers using a "Pascal's triangle" approach, see for example [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Triangle_scheme_for_calculations).